# Visual Studio: How to activate compile errors?

Tags: visual-studio

sorry, this is not a very nice question for here, but I'm very stressed right now and i have to finish sth. now, so...

I accidentially deactivated compile errors in Visual Basic and I cannot find the option to reactivate. Google doesn't help, and manuals, too.

Please help :(

Thx very much!
fLo

EDIT:

It's about the errors when, for example, I run the following code:

```
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 9999999999999999999
```

Then, usually, the program gets stopped and a given error message shows (what type of exception, which row etc.).

Comment: You can't deactivate compile errors, if you have an error in your code, it won't compile, you can't get around that except for fixing the code. Please describe the problem again. For instance, have you lost the error window? Did you disable the red squigglys showing in your code editor?

Comment: That's not a **compiler** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `View`, `Error List`.